# Why do I receive an 'Index out of range error'?

Tags: python, processing

When I run the following code in Processing.py, I get an index out of range error, and I cannot figure out why. All help appreciated.

```
x = 0
y = 0
rand = random(255)

def setup():
   size(200, 200)


def draw():
    global x, y, rand
    loadPixels()
    for i in range(0, width):
        x += 1
        for j in range(0, height):
            y += 1
            index = (x + y*width)*4
            pixels[index + 0] = color(rand)
            pixels[index + 1] = color(rand)
            pixels[index + 2] = color(rand)
            pixels[index + 3] = color(rand)
    updatePixels()
```

Comment: Are `width` and `height` defined by you and if so what would be the value?

Comment: Please show us the full error message

Comment: you didn't provide what is `pixels` here. Regardless, why are you using globals and updating `x` and `y`? Your code is bound to have index errors because your `y` variable increases according to the `height` for *every iteration* of `i` from 0 to width.

Comment: did you initialize the pixels array? How does your loadPixels() function look like?

Comment: Leaving all that aside though, why didn't you just use `i` and `j` instead directly? Shouldn't they have the values you want? Avoid globals as much as you can.

Comment: @uprego Please consider the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. So  `width` and `height` a re well defined

Comment: The full error message: IndexError: array.array assignment index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the out of range error, because `x` and `y` is never reset to 0 and in the filed of [`pixels[]`](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html) there is not one element for each color channel, there is one [`color()`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html) element for each pixel:

```py
index = x + y*width
pixels[index] = color(rand, rand, rand)
```

You've to set `x=0` and `y=0` before the corresponding loop and you've to increment `x` and `y` at the end of the loop:

```py
def draw():
    global x, y, rand
    loadPixels()
    x = 0 
    for i in range(0, width):
        y = 0
        for j in range(0, height):
            index = x + y*width
            pixels[index] = color(rand, rand, rand)
            y += 1
        x += 1
    updatePixels()
```

---

If you want to generate a random color for each pixel, you've to use generate an random value for each color channel of each pixel:

```py
pixels[index] = color(random(255), random(255), random(255))
```

or

```py
pixels[index] = color(*(random(255) for _ in range(3)))
```

Further you can simplify the code. Instead of `i` and `j` you can use `x` and `y` directly. e.g.:

```py
def draw():
    loadPixels()
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            pixels[y*width + x] = color(random(255), random(255), random(255))
    updatePixels()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. However, if I try to run the following, the error still persists, and I'm still not sure why.

    `def draw():  <br/>
        loadPixels()  <br/>
        for x in range(width):  <br/>
            for y in range(height):  <br/>
                index = y*width + x  <br/>
                pixels[index] = color(random(255))  <br/>
                pixels[index+1] = color(255)  <br/>
        updatePixels()`

Comment: @DanielRasmussen Yes of course. Why do you do that? For the last pixel `index+1` is out of range. What do you expect by `pixels[index+1] = color(255)`? It is overwritten immediately by `pixels[index] = color(random(255))` in the next run of the loop.

Comment: I was following the example in this video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikwNrFvnL3g&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bgPNQAdxQZpJuJCjeOr7VD&index=5&t=0s&frags=pl%2Cwn], and in there he does exactly that. He writes in Javascript if that makes a difference. Needless to say, I'm not an experienced programmer.

Comment: @DanielRasmussen The maximum index is `width*height-1` = 39999. If `index==39999` then `index+1` is `40000` and that is out of range. I don't wont to look a youtube video with a nervous clown. Except of that the guy is using javascript and [p5.js](https://p5js.org/). This is slightly different.

Comment: @DanielRasmussen I just figured out that the behavior of processing [`pixels`](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html) is different to that one of p5.js [`pixels`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels). Probably you want to to something like `pixels[index] = color(random(255), 255, 255)`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using greyscale, so color(random(255)) works for me. But it's working now, so let's concider this resolved. Thanks for helping.